# Control gdb running on remote target

Tags: c++, linux, gdb

I have ability to run `gdb` on remote target and if I debug directly on this remote, everything is good. But the problem that I don't want to use pure command line gdb.

I want:

1. Integrate remote gdb with host QT Creator
2. Highlight source code when debugging remote

Also I want try to avoid using remote debugging by `gdbserver`, because it's too difficult and I've encountered multiple problems.
These problems:

1. On host machine I have to have copy of application
2. All multiple shared libraries should be resolved (with the same version)
3. Leads to have copy of remote root filesystem or to mount this one by sshfs.
4. ...

If it is possible I'll just write plugin for QT Creator.

Can't I control remote gdb and send them commands like `"break"`, `"run"`, `"print"`?

Comment: You can connect to the remote host via ssh and start gdb in it..

Comment: You don't have to have a local copy of the application if you use "set sysroot remote:"